# Unit Testing: Accessing element's scope with element.scope() vs element.scope().$$childHead

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

According to [Unit Testing Directive Scope](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-unit-testing-directive-scope), I should be able to access a directive's scope variable in a unit test this way:

```
  expect(element.scope().clicked).toBe(true);
```

Ie., in a test that looks like this...

```
it("should respond to a click", function() {
  browserTrigger(element, "click");
  expect(element.scope().clicked).toBe(true);
}
```

However, in my own experiment I had to do this:

```
  expect(element.scope().$$childHead.clicked).toBe(true);
```

(also, if I did not use isolated scope then it worked without `$$childHead`.)

Why (and when) do I have to use $$childHead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to do it:

```
  expect(element.isolateScope().clicked).toBe(true);
```